# Problema al crear un nuevo proyecto en angualar 7

Tags: angular, angular7

He creado un proyecto en Angular 7 y al momento de crear el proyecto y me sale el siguiente error.
Creo que falta algún componente de el angular-cli pero no se como podría agregarlo

```
npm ERR! path /home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       '/home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53' },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open \'/home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/home/develope/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ff/48/b9ec9e3ff95d922f518722d9e95ab7c1f0383a7bd5e16229ac8d51733b53',
npm ERR!   parent: 'readdirp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/develope/.npm/_logs/2019-08-05T16_02_43_385Z-debug.log
```

y tan poco lo pude ejecutar al momento de ejecutar lo me salto el siguiente error  el cual dice que tengo un error con el siguiente componente de angular-cli @angular-devki

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/var/www/html/angular_sprint/mkultma".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/var/www/html/angular_sprint/mkultma".
    at Object.resolve (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:99:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Observable.toPromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:97:16)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:67:96)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
```

Comment: como instalaste tu angular/cli? agrega tu SO

Comment: lo instale por npm, pero esta versión de angular la llevo utilizando varios meses y apenas ahora me salto ese error

Comment: Parece que es error de los permisos de npm, podría pasar por alguna actualización.  https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally